# Google Groups API wrong output

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

In Google Script Project I have 2 Google-API functions that should give out the same output.
can somebody please explain to me what I am wrong with, or maybe is it a bug in the API?

I have **a group with 904 members**.
Function "listMembersOfGroup1" is **using the "GroupsManager" API**, and is working correctly. **the Logger displais "904.0"**.
And here is the code:

```
function listMembersOfGroup1() {
  var group = GroupsManager.getGroup("group@domain.com");
  var members = group.getAllMembers(); 
Logger.log(members.length);
}
```

But function "listMembersOfGroup2", which is **using the "GroupsApp" API**, is not working correctly (as far I understand). **the Logger displais "753.0"**.
And here is the code:

```
function listMembersOfGroup2() {
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("group@domain.com");
  var users = group.getUsers();
Logger.log(users.length);
}
```

Is there any good reason why the **"GroupApp" API** gives out a different number?

Thanks in advance for your help.

.

(This is my first question on my first day on this site, I hope my question follows the rules.)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Your post was well explained.

The first API GroupsManager is used by domain administrators to manage their domain groups [Check Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/groups-manager).

The secong one GroupsApp is used to manage google groups [Google Groups API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/groups-app).

Your second call is retrieving users that belongs to the google groups mail passed as URL. Check full documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/groups-app#getGroupByEmail%28String%29)

So you're working with different google products.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, and thank you for your answer.

I know that they are 2 different products.

My question is:
Why does "Groupapp...group.lenght" list me 753 users on a group that really has 904 members in it. and all of them have the exact same permission level and settings.

Comment: What do you mean by "Your second call is retrieving users that belongs to the **google groups mail passed as URL**"?

Comment: Sorry, not URL but mail. You have a group wich their mail is the one that you passed as parameter. The list that you retrieve contains all users that participate to this group.

Comment: What I am thinking now is that "GroupsApp...getUsers" lists only **Google Users**, which means, either Gmail accounts or Google Apps accounts. external domains which are not Google Apps users, are not listed in the **"getUsers"** method, and are only listed in a **"members"** method, such as "getAllMembers". Do you think that this is correct?

Comment: No, my previous assumption was wrong, because it lists also Yahoo accounts. but I see there a certain error, I see that when I log the names of the email addresses of the "users" to the logger, it stops in middle of the 753'rd address, and that last address displays in the logger only partly. so I am suspisious that there is a certain error or bug that causes - either the logger or the code - to stop before it really finished. Comment please.

Comment: Maybe this is stopping to avoid log overflow.
I guess that not all your users accepted being part of your google group.